# Subquery with rows havingthe same value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem in Tsql statement.
I have two tables

Item table:

```
Id  name qty
1    a    1
2    b    5
3    c    7
```

Extend table:

```
Id   itemid   active
1      1        true
2      1        true
3      1        false
4      2        true
5      2        true
6      3        false
7      3        true
```

I want query to select all the rows in item table when all the related rows in extends table are true

The result here should be

```
One row
2 b 7
```

Can any one help me?
Thanks

Comment: *"Can any one help me?" I'm sure that can, but [“Can someone help me?” isn't an actual question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). What have *you* tried to solve the problem? What research have you done to try and achieve this? Why didn't those attempts work or what didn't you understand about said research?

Comment: and if no row exists in the `Extend table` Does that also counts as `no false found` ?

Comment: Your expected result is wrong, you want `2 b 5` instead of `2 b 7`

Comment: Where does the `7` in your expected result comes from ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT i.*
FROM Itemtable i
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM Extendtable e
    WHERE i.id = e.itemid AND e.active = 'false'
)
```

Comment: This also shows all rows in the `Itemtable` that have no rows in the `Extend` table. Not sure if the OP wants that or not, he did not say. So maybe better  mention that

Comment: @GuidoG: yes, but OP hasn't mentioned that this is possible or that it would be wrong(if it was possible). It was easy to fix, once we know that it has to be fixed :)